Magento 2.4 open source reindexing issue
I have 600000 products, 6000 categories and multiple attributes set and attributes
10 stores and 20 store views
This will create large set of data in Magento 2 open source in eav and creates indexing issues
indexing is taking more than 24 hours.
Anyway to optimise indexing and get it done in faster way?
Hosted on gcp with similar multiple
Magento instances on different kubernates PODs
Using common elastic search and MySQL service.
Mysql 8 common service for all magento installation.
Php 8.1
Elastic search 7 with elastic suite on different pod but common service
Varnish cache on different pod
Magento 2.4.6-p3 on different pod
Cron on different pod
Indexing set on update on schedule.

Our recommendation when dealing with high amount of attributes and products on our websites on this version is to have the patches updated on the system.
The following patches are recommended (search them here):

ACSD-53728: Fixes the issue where the product EAV indexer is taking longer to complete.
ACSD-53795: Fixes the issue with invalid data type in indexer_update_all_views cron job.
ACSD-53347: Fixes the issue where the price indexer takes too much time to execute.

Also, we recommend to move up 2.4.6-p7 to also avoid issues with CosmicSting, version which applies security patch apsb24-40
To apply this patches you will need the Quality Patch Tool
Should be good to know if those patches improves the performance on the indexing. Do you have the index updates on schedule or on save?

The best approach usually comes down to three key things:
Double-check that your indexer processes are using the right batch size, optimized for your hardware and the amount of data you're working with.
Ensure your cron jobs are set to run each group separately, so one task doesn’t hold up the others.
Make sure there's enough RAM allocated to handle your indexing processes efficiently.
Getting these in place should help everything run much more smoothly!
